# Atom adds new indent line when saving .py script

Tags: python, atom-editor

Since the last update (dont remember exactly which) Atom changed its behaviour when saving .py scripts.

I'm not a programmer, so I tend to write lines of code rather than use indent lines to help the reading of the code. So the problem is:

When I write a line of code Atom keep it a single line, for example

```
clm_anomaly.sel(lat=-12.75, lon=-70.75).rolling(time=12).mean().plot(label='CLM4.5')
```

But when I save the file, the line is divided in two, for example:

```
clm_anomaly.sel(lat=-12.75, lon=-
                70.75).rolling(time=12).mean().plot(label='CLM4.5')
```

I've tried:

- changing the configuration of whitespace base package
- disabling whitespace
- extending the max screen line length to 10000
- disabling soft wrap

Thanks for you help.

Comment: sounds like you have some sort of unwanted linting behavior.  If python can compile and your script runs, I would let it change your scripts to be more readable.  Your future self will thank you.

Comment: Launch Atom in safe mode (`atom --safe`)to rule out this behavior is caused by a third-party package. If this is true you will have to identify the package *you* installed that causes this.

Comment: hi! based on the @idleberg idea, I just reinstalled Atom from scratch. I only installed Hydrogen package to use Python scripts and it works! Thank you!